# Code::blocks complaining about type of parameter

Tags: c++, reference, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I am building a 3D Game Engine. I have build many in other languages, but finally decided to reap the speed benefits of C++ (despite not knowing it particularly well).

I have a class called `EngineOptions` that I use to store information about how the engine is to be initialized. The engine's main class, `Monolith`, then takes a `const` reference to the options instance like so:

```
monolith::EngineOptions options();
monolith::Monolith engine(options);
```

`Monolith` has a correct header file and a constructor like this:

```
Monolith::Monolith(const EngineOptions& options) :  m_options(options)
{
    m_window(m_options.windowWidth, m_options.windowHeight, m_options.windowTitle);
}
```

While I think this is correct, the compiler is complaining that there is:

```
no matching function for call to 'monolith::Monolith::Monolith(monolith::EngineOptions (&)())'
```

Excuse me if I'm being stupid, but I think this code is correct, am I wrong?
I am using the Code::Blocks IDE with the standard GCC toolchain provided on my system.

Comment: You've just encountered the Most Vexing Parse issue. When you do `monolith::EngineOptions options();` you are declaring a _function_ named `options` that returns a `monolith::EngineOptions`.

Comment: `monolith::EngineOptions options();`  Question for you -- what is that line supposed to do?

Comment: Okay, thank you both very much, I thought I was initializing the variable as I had read in a reference book, but I guess this isn't correct; how would I do this correctly, especially if it isn't an empty constructor such as this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from this line:

```
monolith::EngineOptions options();
```

The compiler thinks you're declaring a function returning an `EngineOptions` instance.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much. I was attempting to initliase the variable, like I might do in Java with ``` EngineOptions options = new EngineOptions(); ``` How might I do this correctly in C++? Thank you very much.

Comment: It **is** initialised.  What you have there is an instance of `EngineOptions`, having had its default constructor called on it.  It's not a reference or a pointer; there's no need for `new`.

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you very much @RitchieHindle. What if the constructor wasn't empty, does it then work like I've initialised the instance of Monolith?